# Identifying Proper Sub Games

Tags: game-theory

Does this game have one or two proper games? 
I think FB definitely is, but is UD?[Extensive form game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DTMw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember subgames always have to start at a trivial information set. In this case, $FB$ is not a subgame because in the left part of your tree, we see that player $2$ is not informed of the choice that player $1$ made, meaning the information set is non-trivial.

In the right part of your tree we see that player $2$ makes no decision, meaning that it can't be a subgame because only $1$ player is participating in this ''game''.